# Error with Plink with WMI

Tags: powershell, ssh, wmi, plink

I have a powershell script that uses Plink ssh.  The script works but I need to get it to work through C# and WMI

The problematic line of the powershell script is 
c:/temp/plink.exe -ssh user1@192.168.60.202 -pw password1

When I try to use it through WMI I get the error 'The server's host key is not cached in the registry...'

Do I need a host key corresponding to the WMIEndpoint?
What are the steps to create the necessary keys for the WMI endpoint?

Below is the code from a console app which reproduces the problem

```
        private static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string s)
        {
            var ss = new SecureString();
            foreach (var passChar in s) ss.AppendChar(passChar);
            return ss;
        }

        private static void RunScriptAsPrivilegedAccount(string userAndDomain, string privilegedPassword, string endPointUrl, string script)
        {
            var ss = ConvertToSecureString(privilegedPassword);

            var psCredential =
                new PSCredential(userAndDomain, ss);

            var winRmEndpoint = new Uri(endPointUrl);

            var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(winRmEndpoint,
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", psCredential);


            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                    powershell.AddScript(script);

                    powershell.Invoke();

                    if((powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0))
                    {
                        string errorMessage = String.Join(",",powershell.Streams.Error.Select(
                            x => x.Exception.Message).ToArray());

                        throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage);                               
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunScriptAsPrivilegedAccount(
                "AdminAccount@myDomain.com",
                "adminPwd",
                "http://localhost:5985/wsman",
                "c:/temp/plink.exe -ssh user1@192.168.60.202 -pw password1");

            try
            {
                Console.Write("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to pre-cache the host key of the host with the IP address 192.168.60.202. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17549535/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

piping in a Y did the trick

the line is now Y | c:/temp/plink.exe -ssh user1@192.168.60.202 -pw password1